# How to display remote images with pebble.js

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I'm trying to display remote images on my pebble watch using pebble.js on PebbleCloud.
I found [this intesting topic on Pebble blog](http://developer.getpebble.com/blog/2014/10/29/Displaying-remote-images/) but doesn't help me.

Images are already converted on my server.

If anyone can help me ?

Comment: Are you using any C at all? That link involves the usage of C and Pebble.JS. I believe displaying the remote images will require the usage of both.